# C++ - why isn't size/ssize defined for tuple (or wherever tuple_size_v is)?

Tags: c++, stl, tuples

I'm trying to imagine a scenario where `std::size` is inappropriate for `std::tuple` and I'm coming up blank. It supports `std::array`, but that has its own `size()` method, so there's no need to specialize. But it also supports `T[N]`, presumably because it's statically sized even if it doesn't have a `size()` method (it doesn't even have `std::tuple_size_v`.)

So why doesn't `std::tuple` get `std::size` support *or* a `size()` method? I even thought maybe having `std::tuple_size_v` means it doesn't need one, but the same goes for `std::array`.

Comment: How about [std::tuple_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size)?

Comment: I suspect the reason is that `std::tuple` is not designed for iteration. It's intended to be used more like a `struct`.

Comment: `std::tuple` has a `size` member, which is set at compile time, so doesn't need to be a member function.

Comment: @FredLarson, I mentioned `std::tuple_size` several times. `std::size` has lots of overloads and appears to be designed with generic programming in mind. As it is, I would have to use SFINAE to check for `std::size`, for a `size` member, and `std::tuple_size_v`, and arbitrarily order them to avoid ambiguity between them. Remember, this is not just about `std::tuple`, check the title. BTW @Peter I don't see that 'size' member, are you sure?

Comment: @JohnP: Well, you mentioned `std::tuple_size_v`. I can't find that documented in cppreference, though now I see they do use it in the example code on the page I linked. Curious.

Comment: what about [std::tuple_size](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple_size/)?

Comment: Ah, ok. I found [`std::tuple_size_v` on another page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple_size).

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper You serious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, some background to understand what the purpose of `std::size` even is:

Similar to how iterators are generalisations of what pointers are, the standard containers are generalisations of what arrays are (pointers being iterators of arrays). They all contain elements of homogeneous types i.e. all elements have the same type, and they can be iterated over.

Unlike pointers which do actually satisfy the abstract iterator concept, arrays were not given the same honour. This may have been because the interface of pointer/iterator could be satisfied by a few simple operators, while containers required several functions to use. Perhaps the committee preferred the object oriented interface of member functions over free functions that are the only possibility for arrays.

It can nevertheless be useful to write generic functions and classes that can treat arrays through the same interface. Although an array wrapper template was introduced in C++11 (`std::array`), which actually is a container (well, almost; it doesn't satisfy a few properties that containers are required to have), it cannot satisfy all use cases where refactoring is not an option (consider for example C interfaces).

C++11 and later versions also introduced free functions (templates) that do nothing but forward the call to the corresponding member function of a container, overloaded with a template that does the identical operation on an array. These overloads are such generic interface that can be used with arrays and containers within templates. They are:

```
std::swap      C++11
std::{c,}begin C++11
std::{c,}end   C++11

std::size      C++17
std::empty     C++17
std::data      C++17
```

Besides being generic, `std::end` and `std::size` in particular also implement functionality that is error prone to beginners.

---

Now for the question:

> why isn't size/ssize defined for tuple (or wherever tuple_size_v is)?

The original proposal is [n4017](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4017.htm). It contains no rationale for not supporting tuples. I don't know if the committee ever even thought to consider it. But if they did, since such feature isn't in the standard, then they would have rejected (tenatively at minimum) the idea.

Tuple isn't a container, and it doesn't have the member function `size`. It's significantly further from a container than an array is. Crucially, the elements of a tuple are heterogeneous; they consist of objects of differing types. They cannot be iterated over with iterators in the same sense that containers can be.

Tuples could however be seen as an even higher generalisation of containers. Perhaps in distant future, Boost.Fusion will be incorporated into the standard and we will have a common interface with containers and tuples. But if we are in that timeline, then we are still in the relative past. It won't happen until/unless it has been proposed and accepted into the standard.

---

Curiously, `std::tuple_size` is a common interface between `std::tuple` and `std::array` (but not bare array).

Comment: Very well put, thank you! I was thinking of size in the abstract as the number of elements/members, which would be independent of the types, hence `tuple_size`. If it's clear that it's intended for pointer arithmetic, I can't object. I guess I'm still a little confused when it comes to `array<T,N>` since it appears to have `size()` as if it were dynamic and the other iterator functions, but supports `get<I>`, which won't work on `T[N]`, etc.

Comment: @JohnP `std::array` has `size` because it's supposed to be a container (as much as it can be), and containers are required to have `size`.

Comment: Well said!  A `tuple<int, char, double>` is much closer in spirit to a `struct { int _0; char _1; double _2; };` than a C-style array or any of the containers.

Comment: For what it's worth the page on containers gives a pretty lenient definition, so I'll have to take your word for it. People seem to think it's a container but I didn't see any serious debate. (https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-c-array-containers.html) In languages like Python it's a container but who knows what they've got going on.